# Cocos2D - adding support for normalized position

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, add-on

I want cocos2d to use the nodes' position as a normalized factor when coordinates are less than 1, and otherwise when coordinates are greater than 1, I want cocos2d to treat coordinates as it would normaly do

For instace position (1,1) would locate the node at the top-right corner of the screen, while (.5,.5) would locate the node on the center of the screen.

I was thinking on rewriting the code just where cocos2d pass on the coordinates to the vertex buffer like the following pseudo code

```
if (Position.x <= 1)
    BufferPosition.x = Screen.Width * Position.x;
else
    BufferPosition.x = Position.x;

if (Position.y <= 1)
    BufferPosition.y = Screen.Height * Position.y;
else
    BufferPosition.y = Position.y;
```

So my question is where would you put this code so that cocos2d works that way with no problem, or what approach would you take istead if it's different from the shown above

**Update**

I changed every single call/assignment of `positionInPixels_` in the entire cocos2d library for `positionInPixels`

This means that each time, the corresponding getter and setter is caled instead of the CCNode's positionInPixels_ member variable.

Then I changed `setPosition`, and `setPositionInPixels` in `CCNode.m` like this

***setPosition***

```
-(void) setPosition: (CGPoint)newPosition
{
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

position_ = newPosition;

if (position_.x <= 1.0) {
    positionInPixels_.x = position_.x * winSize.width;
}
else
{
    if( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 1 )
        positionInPixels_.x = position_.x;
    else
    positionInPixels_.x = newPosition.x * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
}

if (position_.y <= 1.0) {
    positionInPixels_.y = position_.y * winSize.height;
}
else
{
    if( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 1 )
    positionInPixels_.y = position_.y;
    else
    positionInPixels_.y = newPosition.y * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
}

isTransformDirty_ = isInverseDirty_ = YES;
#if CC_NODE_TRANSFORM_USING_AFFINE_MATRIX
isTransformGLDirty_ = YES;
#endif
}
```

***setPositionInPixels***

```
-(void) setPositionInPixels:(CGPoint)newPosition
{
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

positionInPixels_ = newPosition;

if (position_.x <= 1.0) {
    position_.x = positionInPixels_.x / winSize.width;
}
else
{
    if( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 1 )
    position_.x = positionInPixels_.x;
    else
    position_.x = newPosition.x * 1/CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() / winSize.width;
}

if (position_.y <= 1.0) {
    position_.y = positionInPixels_.y / winSize.height;
}
else
{
    if( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 1 )
    position_.y = positionInPixels_.y;
    else
    position_.y = newPosition.y * 1/CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() / winSize.height;
}

isTransformDirty_ = isInverseDirty_ = YES;
#if CC_NODE_TRANSFORM_USING_AFFINE_MATRIX
isTransformGLDirty_ = YES;
#endif
}
```

This is working so far, even when using normalized coordinates with CCActionInterval

Comment: good luck with that, in regards to maintainability. I am pretty sure you will soon find a legitimate use case for x,y values < 1 , normalized positions > 1 , etc... and also that positionInPixels is not part of cocos2d version 2.0.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I know it is not best practice to modify the library, but just in this case (using v1.x) would help me to get the desired result, I hope the latest version would add a feature like that, it would come in handy with different screen sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you really think that this variant is the right one? To change the whole framework instead of just adding one method to the CCNode's extension? I think you will see a lot of problem with positioning very soon.

Also it is not good, that (1.f, 1.f) is always have coordinates (screenWidth, screenHeight). You will have a lot of troubles with small nodes. IMHO if you need such positioning, it is much more appropriate to connect this "factor" coordinates to the node's parent size.
Just do restore cocos2d framework and add your own extension to your project. For example,

```
@interface CCNode(FactorPositioning)
- (void) setPositionFactor:(CGFloat) factor;
@end

@implementation CCNode(FactorPositioning)
- (void) setPositionFactor:(CGFloat) factor
{
    assert(self.parent != nil);

    // do your calculations relatieve to the parent's content size
}
@end
```

Comment: Well, the reason is that I'm using a the legacy version 1.x, which won't be updated anymore AFAIK, and using such extention would need to traverse the entire nodes' tree when there is an oriantation change to update each node's position. I wonder why Cocos2D doesn't support this feature out of the box.

Comment: ok. if you wanna do so, you can just create CCNode subclass that will support such kind of resizing (i mean, react to the orientation changes, implement factor positioning, etc.)

Comment: Ok, I reverted the changes and will do what you suggested, that will work with Cocos2D v2.x too which is a better option

Comment: since it can't be added new member variables on the class extension, how can I keep track which nodes respond to UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, and reprogram CCNode to remove themself as observers when are released?